# #VALUE! error referencing single cell range with Evaluate Index

Tags: vba, excel, evaluate

I want to convert to upper case a selected range in Excel.
Here's my code

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
rng.Value = rng.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & rng.Address & "),)")
```

It works on a large range, but gives the #VALUE! error when only a single cell is selected.

Comment: Is this a function or a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cut your selection down to the used range in case you have selected an entire column or row.
2. Process a single cell if you only have a single cell selected; process in bulk for any multiple cell selections.

   ```
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)
   If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
       rng.Value = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & rng.Address & "),)")
   Else
       rng = UCase(rng.Value)
   End If
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for single cell or a selection:

```
Sub ChangeCellCase()

Dim CellCase

   For Each CellCase In Selection
      CellCase.Value = UCase(CellCase.Value)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Beware that this may take some time if applying it to a lot of cells. Would be faster to take entire range into memory, convert it to uppercase, then write it back to the sheet one time. If the use case is a small number of cells then this may not be worth looking into.